# Django : set value to a form render field with button click

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I want to set value on a render field in a Django form
I have the field "desc":

```
 {% render_field form.desc class="form-control"  maxlength="100" id="areasdescr" name="areasdescr" %}
```

and I want to set a value in a button click

Can you help me do this?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward:

1. Add a button. e.g.:

```
    <button class="btn" id="btnAutoDescr">autogenerate description<button>
```

2. Add an EventListener to the button:

with jQuery:

```
$('#btnAutoDescr').on('click', function () {
  $('#areadescr').val('example Text');
});
```

without jQuery:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btnAutoDescr');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('areadescr').value='example Text';
});
```

Edit: Of course that EventListener needs to retrieve the InputElement (e.g. via Id; as shown above) that represents the field and edit it's value.

Comment: Hi. None of the above works.The only one works is this : $('input[name="test"]').val('ADRIAN');   but not for {% render_field .... %}. It works only for <input ..... > fields

Comment: oh i thought the `id='areadescr'` would set the HTML-attribute `id` of the resulting element, but it seems that assumption is wrong. Your answer above seems like you found a solution. It seems like the id is `'desc'`. If that is correct you can just replace `'areadescr'` with `'desc'` and `'#areadescr'` with `'#desc'` and my answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

the right way is :

```
$('#desc').val('example Text');
```

because of :

```
{% render_field form.desc ....
```

areadescr is not working !!!!

Thanks a lot